# function tolower() not converting

Tags: c, tolower

What is wrong with this piece of code? I can't find out what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = "OKAY";

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        tolower(s[i]);

    printf("\n%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
OKAY
```

Comment: Read the documentation of `tolower()`, and think about what your code does.

Comment: Actually, there is nothing "*wrong with the code*".

Comment: BTW, `tolower()` is so past-century. It doesn't handle some edge cases (german ß/SS, turkish I/ı/i, ...). You probably need something like ICU for proper case mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of `tolower` to `s` but this will invoke undefined behavior because string literals are non-modifiable as they are placed on read only section of memory. You can't modify it. Try this instead

```
char s[]= "OKAY";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
```

Comment: You are lucky that `"OKAY"` only contains characters from the basic character set. If it didn’t, the program would lead to *undefined behavior*. See any good documentation of `tolower` for the reason.

Comment: @RolandIllig; Yeah, I know :)

Answer (score 4):

The `tolower` function *returns* the lowercase equivalent of the input character. It doesn't modify it in place.

Answer (score 1):

```
char s[] = "OKAY";

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    s[i]=tolower(s[i]);
```

Comment: @haccks it provides no explanation and consequently it is unhelpful.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I didn't flag this answer.